# Shortcut / Keymap Problems

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a Blender user on Archlinux and some hotkeys are intersecting. There seems to be a hotkey for everything in Arch so I would need to tweak almost every hotkey in blender.

I wondered if there was a way to prioritise a shortcut in Blender over the OS shortcuts. Like `alt click` is move window, but thats also edge select in Blender. I have only found the workaround of rebinding the keys in the OS or Blender so far.

My System: Latest Stable Release from archlinux.org/download,Blender 2.93.3 and German Keyboard Layout

Comment: Which [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_environment) are you using?

Comment: I am using cinnamon. Resetting ti factiry defualts solved this (and rebidning alt to superkey in the cinnamon settings ofc) but i cant use ctrl + click as a shortcut in blender now. It just behaves like normal click. Tho every other shortcut using ctrl works